# How to allow wine to access network shares?

Tags: wine, samba, shared-folders

I've just installed 14.04 from scratch and made MS Word working thanks to wine (1.7.17 from ppa).

The problem is I can't access my network drive shares through wine (I'm in a Office LAN).

With the old Ubuntu 11.10 I just opened .doc files in MS Word and edited, now it seems wine can't access the samba shares that are already mounted in nautilus.

The problem seems to be related to recent changes in Ubuntu's way of mounting network shares:

the old directory: `/home/*username*/.gvfs`
has been replaced by: `/run/user/1000/gvfs`

The names of shares mounted are not readable from wine (so it is trying to open the folder directly from MS word)

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Any other feedback from the computer? Please edit your question to add any relevant messages.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.
I use 13.04 but I think is the same.
The solution is to link the GVFS folder with another name.

Create this file (gvfs-patch) in `/usr/share/playonlinux/bash`:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/playonlinux/bash/gvfs-patch
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=/dev/null

GVFS_HOME=/run/user/$USER/gvfs

# Create BASE folder
BASE=/tmp/POL-$USER-gvfs
if [ ! -d "$BASE" ]; then
   echo "Create BASE folder : $BASE" >> $LOGFILE
   rm -fr $BASE
   mkdir $BASE
else
   echo "BASE folder exists : $BASE" >> $LOGFILE
fi

# Clean old symbolic link
for SHARE in $(ls "$BASE"); do
   if [[ ! -e "$BASE/$SHARE" && -h "$BASE/$SHARE" ]]; then
      echo "Remove OLD share folder : $SHARE" >> /tmp/diego.txt
      rm -f "$BASE/$SHARE"
   else
      echo "Share folder valid : $SHARE" >> $LOGFILE
   fi
done

# Create symbolic link for ALL share
for SHARE in $(ls "$GVFS_HOME"); do
   NSHARE=$(echo $SHARE | sed 's/:/-/g')
   if [ ! -e "$BASE/$NSHARE" ]; then
      echo "Create share folder : $NSHARE" >> $LOGFILE
      ln -s "$GVFS_HOME/$SHARE" "$BASE/$NSHARE"
   else
      echo "Share folder valid : $BASE/$NSHARE" >> $LOGFILE
   fi
done

echo $1 | sed "s|$GVFS_HOME|$BASE|g" | sed 's/:/-/g'
```

Make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/playonlinux/bash/gvfs-patch  
sudo chown root.root /usr/share/playonlinux/bash/gvfs-patch
```

Patch this file: `/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/document_reader`

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/playonlinux/bash/document_reader
```

At line 43 (before realpath=...) add this:

```
doc=$($PLAYONLINUX/bash/gvfs-patch "$doc")
```

Comment: Hi, your workaround seems very good. How can I apply it with a classic Wine installation (instead PlayOnLinux)? I think there's very little differences, but since I'm in a "production" workstation I tend to be very cautious...

Comment: Hi @Francesco, my script converts a share path (gvfs) into a /tmp based path. If you have a variable **doc** (as above) you can convert in this way (sample in bash script): `patcheddoc=$(/your_place_scripts/gvfs-patch) "$doc"`. If doc is not in gvfs path, my script return the input without changes

Comment: Diego, as below I am having problems with permissions as the documents will open using the symlink but only "Read-Only".  Any suggestions or the ability to confirm or deny this security issue are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Diego's answer, I have integrated this into a wine wrapper which can be used for classic Wine installations. I've only targeted the specific instance where wine is run as "wine start" where the path is the 4th argument, but this could be expanded to iterate through all arguments testing for pathnames.

Also for me, the folder in `/run/user` was my UID not username.

Create this file (wine) in `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/local/bin/wine
```

add these contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=/dev/null
GVFS_HOME=/run/user/`id -u $USERID`/gvfs
BASE=/tmp/POL-$USER-gvfs

setupgvfstmp() {
  # Create BASE folder
  if [ ! -d "$BASE" ]; then
     echo "Create BASE folder : $BASE" >> $LOGFILE
     rm -fr $BASE
     mkdir $BASE
  else
     echo "BASE folder exists : $BASE" >> $LOGFILE
  fi

  # Clean old symbolic link
  for SHARE in $(ls "$BASE"); do
     if [[ ! -e "$BASE/$SHARE" && -h "$BASE/$SHARE" ]]; then
        echo "Remove OLD share folder : $SHARE" >> /tmp/diego.txt
        rm -f "$BASE/$SHARE"
     else
        echo "Share folder valid : $SHARE" >> $LOGFILE
     fi
  done

  # Create symbolic link for ALL share
  for SHARE in $(ls "$GVFS_HOME"); do
     NSHARE=$(echo $SHARE | sed 's/:/-/g')
     if [ ! -e "$BASE/$NSHARE" ]; then
        echo "Create share folder : $NSHARE" >> $LOGFILE
        ln -s "$GVFS_HOME/$SHARE" "$BASE/$NSHARE"
     else
        echo "Share folder valid : $BASE/$NSHARE" >> $LOGFILE
     fi
  done
}

if [ "$1" = "start" ] &&  [ -e "$4" ]; then
  # This only fiddles with stuff if the path is in $4, cos thats what my desktop shortcuts seem to do
  #env WINEPREFIX="/home/phil/.wine" wine start /ProgIDOpen Excel.Sheet.12 %f
  START=$1
  WHAT=$2
  FLAG=$3
  TARGET=$4
  shift 4
  echo "$TARGET" | grep $GVFS_HOME > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ "$?" == 0 ]; then
    # Because gvfs sometimes hangs for me, only do this if the path is in gvfs
    setupgvfstmp
    TARGET=`echo $TARGET | sed "s|$GVFS_HOME|$BASE|g" | sed 's/:/-/g'`
  fi
  /usr/bin/wine "$START" "$WHAT" "$FLAG" "$TARGET" "$@"
else
  /usr/bin/wine "$@"
fi
```

Make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wine
```

Make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your $PATH, and comes before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: My problem is that I can get files to open using this symlink method, but all files are opening "Read Only" in MSOffice 2007.  Did you run into this problem?  I will need to try with other versions of MSOffice and / or different versions of wine and / or different configurations of wine.  I am in Ubuntu 18.04 with wine-development providing wine-3.6